# How to iterate through a json dict of arrays using loop postgresql

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, function, loops

I am trying to iterate through a json dict of arrays in postgres using a function.
input json:
'{"Key1": ["value1", "value2", "value3"],"key2":["value4","value5"]}';

On trying to access individual elements as text(without quotes) for further processing,I am getting an error.

the input for my function is a json dictionary below :
`datajson json: '{"Key1": ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"],"Default":["value5","value6"]}';` 
Body of my function:

```
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        keys text[];
        key text;
        value text;
        element text;

    BEGIN
        for key in select json_object_keys(datajson) loop
      raise notice '%', key;
        for value in (select json_array_elements(datajson->key) )
        loop
          raise notice '%', value;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    end;

    $BODY$ language plpgsql
```

On doing this,I get an error :

```
NOTICE:   key1
NOTICE:   "value1"
ERROR:  Got exception:
state  : 22P02
message: malformed array literal: ""value1""
detail : Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.
```

How should I loop through to get the required array elements( text without the quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message clearly indicates that the value being processed is not "array literal", because it is starting an ending with quotes.

You can fix this issue by using "[json_array_elements_text()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html)" function, it returns JSON values as text.